# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and') when updating to Next JS 13

Tags: html, next.js

I ran into this issue after upgrading from Next JS 12 to Next JS 13.
Every time I run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` I am met with this:

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')
    at Object.webpack (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next-transpile-modules\src\next-transpile-modules.js:206:60)
    at getBaseWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js:2164:32)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
    at async webpackBuildImpl (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-build\impl.js:133:21)
    at async webpackBuild (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-build\index.js:137:16)
    at async C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:595:123
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
    at async build (C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\VSCProjects\my_project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:148:29)
- info Creating an optimized production build .
```

At this point I am not quite sure how to fix it. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages with `npm ci` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

At this point I am not quite sure how to fix it. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages with `npm ci` but it doesn't seem to work. I have not tried to delete the entire node-modules folder yet because of worries whether it would put my project in jeapoardy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the next-transpile-modules package which is no longer needed and deprecated with NextJS 13.1. You can follow the instructions here to use Nextjs built in transpiler which hopefully will solve the issue.  https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/releases/tag/the-end

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This fix works 